# Is it possible to scope constructor injection in dagger 2?

Tags: java, dagger-2

I have a code something like this and I want to make it scoped. But I found that this is not working and it seems only possible through in a module. I wasn't able to find a proper question for this and is it possible to scope a constructor injection?

Does not work

```
@AppScope
@Inject
public StackOverflow() {
}
```

Scope works!!

```
@Module
public InternetModule {
   @AppScope
   @Provides
   public StackOverflow provideStackOverflow() {
      return new StackOverflow();
   }
}
```

Comment: BTW: `public StackOverFlow()` -> `overflow` and `over flow` are two different things

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put the scope on the class

```
@AppScope
public class Blah {
    @Inject StackOverFlow stackOverflow;

    @Inject 
    public Blah()  {
    }
}
```